# React.js/testing-library/react => TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I'm trying to unit test some of react components, and I got this error with some of the component tests. I have tried many solutions but without any result

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
```

- **Test code**

```
    import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
    import { act } from "react-test-renderer";
    import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
    import { Provider } from "react-redux";
    import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";
    import { initialState } from "./mock";
    import "jest-location-mock";
    import TabsPanel from "../TabsPanel";
    import { usei18n } from "../i18n";
    
    const i18n = usei18n("en");
    
    describe("TabsPanel component", () => {
      const mockStore = configureStore();
      let store = mockStore(initialState);
    
      test("renders TabsPanel without crashing", async () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(
          <Provider store={store}>
            <TabsPanel />
          </Provider>
        );
    
        expect(getByTestId("TabsPanel-component")).toBeTruthy();
      });
    });
```

Comment: You need to look for code that is using `addEventListener`.

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)